# Regex: Select/Find all html tags that contain only 4 words

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this 2 html tags. I want to find all html tags that contain only 4 words (only the first line in my example)

`<p class="mb-40px">My name is prince</p>`

`<p class="mb-40px">Soul Travel is a spiritual practice that enables you to explore</p>`

I try this, but not too good:

FIND: `(<p class="mb-40px">)(.*?)(?:\W*+\w++){1,4}(.*?)</p>`

Comment: [Please don't parse HTML with regex...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2329707)

Comment: that is by far the strangest SO thread I've ever seen. it should have been an April 1st post.
"Every time you attempt to parse HTML with regular expressions, the unholy child weeps the blood of virgins, and Russian hackers pwn your webapp. Parsing HTML with regex summons tainted souls into the realm of the living. HTML and regex go together like love, marriage, and ritual infanticide.". my word...

Comment: beautiful poem :)

Comment: With minor modification, your regex is fine: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:\W*\w+){4}\W*</p>`. Remove the possessive quantifiers and the useless `(.*?)`.

Comment: hello @Toto. Thanks Please post it as an answer and delete this comment. Is better to have more answers than comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do it:

```
<p class="mb-40px">(\w+[^\w]*){4}[^\w]*</p>
```

It searches for the `<p>` tags and in between exactly 4 occurrences
of a word followed by any number of non-word characters
(including zero).

Answer (score 0):

With minor modification, your regex is fine.
Remove the possessive quantifiers `*+` & `++` and the useless `(.*?)`.

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `<p class="mb-40px">(?:\W*\w+){4}\W*</p>`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<p class="mb-40px"> # start tag
  (?:                 # non capture group
    \W*                 # 0 or more non word character
    \w+                 # 1 or more word character
  ){4}                # end group, must appear exactly 4 times
  \W*                 # 0 or more non word character
</p>                # end tag
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]